# NoSuchMethodError and how to read

Tags: java, jenkins, guava, nosuchmethoderror

Executing some Java Code in a Jenkins Plugin, I get the following:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;II)V
    at de.dwpbank.build.jenkins.plugins.templateutility.auxconfig.ConfigHarvester.extract(ConfigHarvester.java:123)
```

And I'm wondering how to fully understand the NoSuchMethodError message:

```
checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;II)V
```

What I get is, I called the checkArgument method with at least a String as a parameter, the L is the size of the pointer (Long - isn't it?) but what does the Z, the II after the semicolon and the V stand for?

Here's the call off checkArgument:

```
int maxBoundary = configDescriptorTree.getMaxBoundary();
int size = auxArray.length;

Preconditions.checkArgument(maxBoundary >= size,
                    "AuxInstance Array size '%s' > maxBoundary '%s'", size,
                    maxBoundary);
```

So this call would match to the following signature of checkArgument:

```
public static void checkArgument(boolean b, @Nullable String errorMessageTemplate, int p1, int p2)
```

Through autoboxing it could also match this one:

```
checkArgument(boolean b, @Nullable String errorMessageTemplate, @Nullable Object p1, @Nullable Object p2)
```

Or this one:

```
public static void checkArgument(boolean expression, @Nullable String errorMessageTemplate, @Nullable Object... errorMessageArgs)
```

Could this ambiguity the reason for the NoSuchMethodError?

I'm wondering that I can execute the call from the Jenkins script console withouth any problem:

```
com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(1 >= 2,
                    "AuxInstance Array size '%s' > maxBoundary '%s'", 2,
                    1);
```

Result

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AuxInstance Array size '2' > maxBoundary '1'
```

Comment: You are passing an illegal argument

Comment: @Lokesh What illegal argument? The method expects boolean, String, int, int and that what it gets.

Comment: Some value may be null. read this doc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically this kind of error messages have to do with library dependencies linking to wrong versions.

The library of `de.dwpbank.build.jenkins.plugins.templateutility.auxconfig.ConfigHarvester` is probably linked to a version of Google Guava which is not available in your Jenkins installation.

If you want to know more which jar files are involved you can run this code to locate the jar files:

```
public static void findJarForClass(Class clazz) {
    CodeSource src = clazz.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource();
    if (src != null) {
        java.net.URL jar = src.getLocation();
        System.out.printf("%s ----> %s%n", clazz, jar);
    }
}
```

This static call will point you to the jar files of the involved classes.

If you know the versions you can inspect the jar file of `de.dwpbank.build.jenkins.plugins.templateutility.auxconfig.ConfigHarvester`, especially in their META-INF/maven folder and see what the pom.xml file says about its dependencies. Typically this file will point you to the expected libraries - in your case to the expected Guava library version.

Comment: Okay, well that's it:

class com.google.common.base.Preconditions ----> file:/data/war/WEB-INF/lib/guava-11.0.1.jar

This NoSuchMethodError occurs in Guava versions < 20, so I have to change my dependecy version and set the scope to provided.

Comment: So in this case, at compile time of ConfigHarvester is decided to use checkArgument(boolean b, String template, int p1, int p2) (which doesn't exist in guava 11) and not checkArgument(boolean expression, String template,  Object... args) (which does exist) and from the Jenkins script console the latter one is used.

Do I get this right?

Comment: Yes, I think you are spot on. The problem you might have right now is how to re-concile the dependencies required by Jenkins and the ConfigHarvester plugin. This might require probably a plugin upgrade or a library update.

Comment: In order to analyze methods in these libraries I use very often a decompiler UI (http://jd.benow.ca/). This helps me often to find solutions for these types of problems. Perhaps it might help you too.